# how to cover values ​that are in a component with tests jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

is it possible to write tests in jest for a component that is, as it were, inside? that is, I do not have the ability to make the data values ​​​​incremental in the function, they are inside the function, just a simplified example

```
export default function App() {
      let test1 = 10;
      let test2 = 5;
    
      if (test1 !== test2) {
        console.log("1");
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bouman-5x293t?file=/src/App.tsx:24-286

Comment: No. But fortunately they don't actually do anything so you don't need to test them. And if they did something, like get displayed to the user, you could test _that_.

Comment: yes but jest writes that row data is not covered

Comment: So, given that again they don't actually do anything, _delete them_. Coverage is bound to improve if you get rid of useless code.

Comment: A bounty isn't going to help, this isn't even a React or Jest issue just basic JS scope - you have no access to `test1` and `test2` from outside `App`. Effectively your component unconditionally logs `1`, which you _could_ test for (that's the _behaviour_, not the implementation) but most likely your example has been "simplified" far past the point where it's a useful representation of your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to test for the private internals of functions.

The only way you could test it, would be by having it in separate function (just a simple util function) and test separately there. After that just import it anywhere you need.

This means doing something like this

```js
const areTestValueMatching = (test1, test2) => {
  if (test1 !== test2) {
      return false;
  }
  return true
}

it("returns true if test values are matching", () => {
  expect(areTestValueMatching(1, 2)).toBe(false)
})
```

And then importing areTestValueMatching function into your function component.